# react typescript state Object is possibly 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, typescript-generics

Im new to using typescript with react. I have an  application where I call an api and set the response to a state. I have created a generic type for api calls as follow.

```
const responseBody = <T>(response: AxiosResponse<T>) => response.data;
const restApiCalls = {
  get: <T>(url: string) => axios.get<T>(url).then(responseBody),
  post: <T>(url: string, body: {}) =>
    axios.post<T>(url, body).then(responseBody),
  put: <T>(url: string, body: {}) => axios.put<T>(url, body).then(responseBody),
};

const users = {
  getUsers: () =>
    restApiCalls.get<Users[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"),
};

const apis = {
  users,
};
export default apis;
```

The `getUser()` function calls the get request and returns a list of `Users`

The following is the `User interface`

```
export interface Users {
  id: boolean;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: Address;
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: Company;
}

interface Address {
  street: string;
  suite: string;
  city: string;
  zipcode: string;
  geo: Geo;
}

interface Geo {
  lat: string;
  lng: string;
}

interface Company {
  name: string;
  catchPhrase: string;
  bs: string;
}
```

When calling the api, the api returns the data successfully and I assigned the returned data to the state using `setUser`method.

Following is the state.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<Users[]>();
```

I assigned the fetched data to state as follow.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await apis.users.getUsers();
      
      setUser(res);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

when console the `user` state, the data is is there and it is logged successfully. But I want to check the length of the user state in a if condition. If I check the length, it show the following error.

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

This is the code I used to check the length

```
 const someFunction= () => {
    if (user?.length > 1) {
      for (let index = 0; index < user?.length; index++) {
        console.log(user[index])
      }
    }
  };
```

But I if set the state type to `any` instead of `User[]`, it works. WHat might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions with `users` are all capable of resolving to `undefined`, which cannot be compared to a number and cannot be indexed.  For example `user?.length` could be undefined (if `user` is undefined); same with `user[index]`

You need to handle the undefined case.  For example:

```
 const someFunction= () => {
    if(!user) { return; }
    if (user.length > 1) {
      for (let index = 0; index < user.length; index++) {
        console.log(user[index])
      }
    }
  };
```